# unexpected number formatting output

Tags: c#, formatting

I know there are plenty of question about this but I ddn't found anything reggarding this.

I try to format number following this format : *value.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("fr-CA"))*. The type of *value* is float. The format apply but not the way I tought it would. I refered to [this article about formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)

Here exemples :

```
123456     display as 123 456.00
123456.789 display as 123 456.79 // rounded
1234.5     display 1 234.50      //added a 0 padding
```

Is there a way to format somthing like this ?

```
123456     display as 123 456    
123456.789 display as 123 456.789 
1234.5     display as 1 234.5
```

Here is the code were I try to apply the formatting

```
private void dgvform_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    float val;
    if ( (e.ColumnIndex == valeur.Index || e.ColumnIndex == valeurEN.Index)
        && dgvform.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[type_d.Index].Value != null && dgvform.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[type_d.Index].Value.ToString() == "N"
        && dgvform.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[valeur.Index].Value != null
        && float.TryParse(dgvform.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[valeur.Index].Value.ToString(), out val))
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == valeurEN.Index)
            e.Value = val.ToString("N", new CultureInfo(_formatEN));
        else
            e.Value = string.Format("{0:# ### ###.####}", val);
    }
}
```

this is part of a datagridview. the big `if` is to determinate if I need to apply formatting to this cell. `valeur`, `valeurEN` are both column were I need to apply formating. `e.Value = val.ToString("N", new CultureInfo(_formatEN));` is the old way I apply the formatting. `_formatEN` is basically "en-US".

Basically I want to add a thousand separator and be sure to use the good decimal separator
any tought about what i'm doing wrong?

/edit : *value* is a type of float

Comment: Please specify the type of `value` (what datatype are you trying to `ToString()`)?

Comment: @DonBoitnott thank you added it in the question

Comment: It's a data type precision issue. See my edit below.

Comment: I kept digging with the data type precision issue and I found another place where the value was casted to a float so this was the reason why i kept lossing my format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would need to build a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

```
value.ToString("#,0.##########", new CultureInfo("fr-CA"))
```

The leading `#,0` part introduces the thousands separator, whilst the trailing `.###…` adds as many fractional digits as is required (up to a maximum corresponding to the number of `#` characters you specified). The `,` and `.` specifiers are not used verbatim, but interpreted according to the current culture.

Refer to http://ideone.com/QypZBP for a sample run:

```
double d = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#,0.##########", new CultureInfo("fr-CA")));
// Output: "12 345,6789"
```

**Edit**: Since you've clarified that you're using a `float`, then the reason why the last digits are getting truncated is due to the limited precision of that data type. Per MSDN, [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) has a precision of 7 digits, meaning that the last two digits are never even stored in your variable. If you want to be able to represent your number, you should change your data type to `double`.

Comment: this doesn't do what I expect. `12345.6789` is formatted as `12 345.68`

Comment: tested it out. with you link and within my application. When I debug it look fine but still formatted as 12 345.68 on the datagridview. Like I mean if I put a break point on `e.Value = val.ToString("#,0.##########", new CultureInfo("fr-CA"));` The value in `e.value` is really `12 345.6789` but on the grid it is `12 345.68`. Any tought?